# Parallel for_each more than two times slower than std::for_each

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm reading [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) by *Anthony Williams*. In the chapter about *designing concurrent code* there is parallel version of [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) algorihtm. Here is slightly modified code from the book:

**join_thread.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class join_threads
{
public:
  explicit join_threads(std::vector<std::thread>& threads)
    : threads_(threads) {}

  ~join_threads()
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads_.size(); ++i)
    {
      if(threads_[i].joinable())
      {
        threads_[i].join();
      }
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::thread>& threads_;
};
```

**parallel_for_each.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <future>
#include <algorithm>

#include "join_threads.hpp"

template<typename Iterator, typename Func>
void parallel_for_each(Iterator first, Iterator last, Func func)
{
  const auto length = std::distance(first, last);
  if (0 == length) return;

  const auto min_per_thread = 25u;
  const unsigned max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;

  const auto hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  const auto num_threads= std::min(hardware_threads != 0 ?
        hardware_threads : 2u, max_threads);

  const auto block_size = length / num_threads;

  std::vector<std::future<void>> futures(num_threads - 1);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads-1);
  join_threads joiner(threads);

  auto block_start = first;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
  {
    auto block_end = block_start;
    std::advance(block_end, block_size);
    std::packaged_task<void (void)> task([block_start, block_end, func]()
    {
      std::for_each(block_start, block_end, func);
    });
    futures[i] = task.get_future();
    threads[i] = std::thread(std::move(task));
    block_start = block_end;
  }

  std::for_each(block_start, last, func);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
  {
    futures[i].get();
  }
}
```

I benchmarked it with sequential version of [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) using the following program:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#include "parallel_for_each.hpp"

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 500'000'000;
typedef std::vector<uint64_t> Array;

template <class FE, class F>
void test_for_each(const Array& a, FE fe, F f, atomic<uint64_t>& result)
{
  auto time_begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  result = 0;
  fe(a.begin(), a.end(), f);
  auto time_end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  cout << "Result = " << result << endl;
  cout << "Time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(
            time_end - time_begin).count() << endl;
}

int main()
{
  random_device device;
  default_random_engine engine(device());
  uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> distribution(0, 255);

  Array a;
  a.reserve(ARRAY_SIZE);

  cout << "Generating array ... " << endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    a.push_back(distribution(engine));

  atomic<uint64_t> result;
  auto acc = [&result](uint64_t value) { result += value; };

  cout << "parallel_for_each ..." << endl;
  test_for_each(a, parallel_for_each<Array::const_iterator, decltype(acc)>, acc, result);
  cout << "for_each ..." << endl;
  test_for_each(a, for_each<Array::const_iterator, decltype(acc)>, acc, result);

  return 0;
}
```

The parallel version of the algorithm on my machine is more than two times slower than sequential one:

```
parallel_for_each ...
Result = 63750301073
Time: 5448
for_each ...
Result = 63750301073
Time: 2496
```

I'm using **GCC 6.2** compiler on *Ubuntu Linux* running on **Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz**.

How such a behavior can be explained? Is this because of sharing of `atomic<uint64_t>` variable between threads and cache ping-pong?

I profiled both separately with **perf**. For the parallel version the stats are the following:

```
 1137982167      cache-references                                            
  247652893      cache-misses              #   21,762 % of all cache refs    
60868183996      cycles                                                      
27409239189      instructions              #    0,45  insns per cycle        
 3287117194      branches                                                    
      80895      faults                                                      
          4      migrations
```

And for the sequential one:

```
  402791485      cache-references                                            
  246561299      cache-misses              #   61,213 % of all cache refs    
40284812779      cycles                                                      
26515783790      instructions              #    0,66  insns per cycle
 3188784664      branches                                                    
      48179      faults
          3      migrations
```

It is obvious that the parallel version generates far more cache references, cycles and faults but why?

Comment: There will be a parallel version of algorithms in C++17 :)

Comment: You're accumulating from multiple threads into the same variable. Seems like you have [a **false sharing**](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206) issue!

Comment: The problem is likely in your function: you're paying for having an atomic variable used by multiple threads concurrently. A typical pattern is to compute intermediate results and then use a reduction pass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are **sharing the same `result` variable**: all the threads are accumulating on `atomic<uint64_t> result`, thrashing the cache!

Every time a thread writes to `result`, all the caches in the other cores are invalidated: this leads to **cache line contention**.

More information:

- ["Sharing Is the Root of All Contention"](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/sharing-is-the-root-of-all-contention/214100002).

  > [...] to write to a memory location a core must additionally have exclusive ownership of the cache line containing that location. While one core has exclusive use, all other cores trying to write the same memory location must wait and take turns — that is, they must run serially. Conceptually, it's as if each cache line were protected by a hardware mutex, where only one core can hold the hardware lock on that cache line at a time.
- [This article on "false sharing"](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206), which covers a similar issue, explains more in depth what happens in the caches.

---

I made some modifications to your program and achieved the following results *(on a machine with an [i7-4770K](http://ark.intel.com/products/75123/Intel-Core-i7-4770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) [8 threads + hyperthreading])*:

```
Generating array ...
parallel_for_each ...
Result = 63748111806
Time: 195
for_each ...
Result = 63748111806
Time: 2727
```

The parallel version is **roughly 92% faster** than the serial version.

---

1. `std::future` and `std::packaged_task` are **heavyweight** abstractions. In this case, an [**`std::experimental::latch`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/latch) is sufficient.
2. Every task is sent to a **thread pool** This **minimizes thread creation overhead**.
3. Every task has **its own accumulator**. This **eliminates sharing**.

The code is available [**here on my GitHub**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/Experiments/blob/master/Random/so/futb/main.cpp). It uses some personal dependencies, but you should understand the changes regardless.

---

Here are the most important changes:

```
// A latch is being used instead of a vector of futures.
ecst::latch l(num_threads - 1);

l.execute_and_wait_until_zero([&]
{
    auto block_start = first;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
    {
        auto block_end = block_start;
        std::advance(block_end, block_size);

        // `p` is a thread pool.
        // Every task posted in the thread pool has its own `tempacc` accumulator.
        p.post([&, block_start, block_end, tempacc = 0ull]() mutable
        {
            // The task accumulator is filled up...
            std::for_each(block_start, block_end, [&tempacc](auto x){ tempacc += x; });

            // ...and then the atomic variable is incremented ONCE.
            func(tempacc);
            l.decrement_and_notify_all();
        });

        block_start = block_end;
    }

    // Same idea here: accumulate to local non-atomic counter, then
    // add the partial result to the atomic counter ONCE.
    auto tempacc2 = 0ull;
    std::for_each(block_start, last, [&tempacc2](auto x){ tempacc2 += x; });
    func(tempacc2);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, something doesn't add up here. With 8 threads the maximum speedup is 8, but this shows a speedup of about 14 (2727/195 = 13.98). Maybe 8 cores, with 2 hyper-threads per core?

Comment: @PeteBecker: yes, it's an i7-4770. Updating the answer.

Comment: This is not false sharing, this is real sharing: all threads share the same accumulator. False sharing is a situation where different threads access different variables, but located in the same cache line.

Comment: @IlyaPopov: thanks for the correction, I updated my answer.